# Unable to start receiver, java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting a Java null pointer exception Unable to start receiver error,

My LogCat

```
04-23 21:55:16.889: I/TextView(8039): *****onCrecateContextMenu::isInputMethodTarget:true, isIMEChangable;true
04-23 21:55:25.479: D/AndroidRuntime(8039): Shutting down VM
04-23 21:55:25.479: W/dalvikvm(8039): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.yp.iss_project.CbReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1809)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at com.yp.iss_project.CbReceiver.onReceive(CbReceiver.java:272)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1798)
04-23 21:55:25.479: E/AndroidRuntime(8039):     ... 10 more
04-23 21:56:57.819: W/KeyCharacterMap(8162): No keyboard for id 0
04-23 21:56:57.819: W/KeyCharacterMap(8162): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-23 21:57:00.359: I/TextView(8162): *****onCrecateContextMenu::isInputMethodTarget:true, isIMEChangable;true
04-23 21:57:08.069: D/AndroidRuntime(8162): Shutting down VM
04-23 21:57:08.069: W/dalvikvm(8162): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.yp.iss_project.CbReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1809)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at andr oid.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at com.yp.iss_project.CbReceiver.onReceive(CbReceiver.java:273)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1798)
04-23 21:57:08.069: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     ... 10 more
04-23 21:59:10.639: I/TextView(8265): *****onCrecateContextMenu::isInputMethodTarget:true, isIMEChangable;true
04-23 21:59:19.979: D/AndroidRuntime(8265): Shutting down VM
04-23 21:59:19.979: W/dalvikvm(8265): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
```

My broadcast receiver is

```
   public static String str;
    public static int my;
    public static String MSG = encrypt.message;
    public final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the CB message passed in---

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsCbMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null)  {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsCbMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsCbMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str = ""; 
                str +="" +msgs[i].getGeographicalScope() + msgs[i].getMessageCode() + msgs[i].getMessageIdentifier() + msgs[i].getUpdateNumber();                     
                my = msgs[i].getGeographicalScope() + msgs[i].getMessageCode() + msgs[i].getMessageIdentifier() + msgs[i].getUpdateNumber();

                if(str != "")
                {
                Toast.makeText(context, "CB: " +str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "MY: " +my, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                {
                          String cipherText="";
                          for(int y=0;y<MSG.length();y++)
                          {

                               int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(MSG.charAt(y));
                               int keyVal = (my + charPosition)%26;
                               char replaceVal = this.ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
                               cipherText += replaceVal;
                          }
                          Toast.makeText(context, "CipherText: " +cipherText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                }
                }
                abortBroadcast();  
                }
```

Comment: What is wrote on line 268 of your code ?

Comment: I am getting the value of MSG passed in from another class, I am checking if it's length is 0 in line 268.

Comment: `if(MSG.length() == 0)`  - this one?

Comment: Yes, that one...I've updated the logcat also

Comment: Then your other class is passing MSG as null, or you are not receiving correctly.  What is this line?  `public static String MSG = encrypt.message;`? Where are you setting `MSG`? Does this code even compile? Do you know how to use the debugger?  if not, you should learn.  Also, please post your logcat as text, not an image.

Comment: Also, don't do `if(str != "")` but `if(!str.equals(""))`

Comment: @Simon encrypt is the class which contains the message text value, the message value is given as input by the user in the encrypt class before the broadcast receiver is started.

Comment: @ZouZou I've removed that, yet the error is at 272 line

Comment: @Simon Thank you!! From your comment I got the idea of what went wrong. I've posted the correct answer and my research supporting it below. I am new to android and I'm learning it by building some apps...Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed

```
public static String MSG = encrypt.message;
```

and replaced all occurrences of MSG with

```
encrypt.message
```

My mistake was with passing the value pf message from the encrypt class, as the MSG value declared in the receiver class is a null I've received a null pointer exception.